# Graphing with transformation: translations or reflections.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$${y = (x - 4)^2}$$

I came up with 4 units to the right but, my problem is how do come up with other points on the parabola?

The second question is ${y = -x^2 - 3}$.

The vertex is ${-3}$. With the same problem as the first question.

Do I just plug on the first one?

Comment: I'm confused! What do you mean by relabel?

Comment: Let me try again. Draw the parabola $y=x^2$, then translate it 4 units to the right (in the direction of increasing $x$). For the second one, reflect $y=x^2$ in the $x$-axis to get $y=-x^2$, then translate it 3 units downwards (in the direction of decreasing $y$).

Comment: I know where the vertexes are supposed to be, but how do I come up with the other points on the parabola?

Comment: For the first one, if you make a table of values for $y = x^2$, you can make a table of values of $y = (x - 4)^2$ by adding $4$ to each $x$-coordinate in the table for $y = x^2$.  For the second one, take your table of values for $y = x^2$, then replace each $y$-value by $-y - 3$.

Comment: Could the width of x be infinite, and at some point just stop and work on Y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's begin with how to determine points on the curve $y = -x^2 - 3$.  The transformation $y = x^2 \to y = -x^2$ has the effect of reflecting the graph of $y = x^2$ in the $x$-axis.  The transformation $y = -x^2 \to y = -x^2 - 3$ has the effect of shifting the graph of $y = -x^2$ down by three units.  In the table below, we start with a set of $x$-values, use them to obtain the corresponding values of $y = x^2$, multiply each $y$-value by $-1$ to obtain the corresponding values of $y = -x^2$, then subtract $3$ from each of those $y$-values to find the corresponding values of $y = -x^2 - 3$.

\begin{array}{c | c | c | c}
x & y = x^2 & y = -x^2 & y = -x^2 - 3\\ \hline
-3 & 9 & -9 & -12\\
-2 & 4 & -4 & -7\\
-1 & 1 & -1 & -4\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -3\\
1 & 1 & -1 & -4\\
2 & 4 & -4 & -7\\
3 & 9 & -9 & -12
\end{array}
The points on the curves $y = x^2$, $y = -x^2$, and $y = -x^2 - 3$ are obtained by matching the $x$-coordinates in the first column with the corresponding $y$-coordinates in the second, third, and fourth columns, respectively.  The graphs of $y = x^2$, $y = -x^2$, and $y = -x^2 - 3$ are shown below in blue, yellow, and magenta, respectively.

[image: reflection_in_x-axis_followed_by_downward_shift_of_squaring_function]

The transformation $y = x^2 \to y = (x - 4)^2$ shifts the graph of $y = x^2$ four units to the right.  This has the effect of adding four to each $x$-coordinate.  In the table below, we start with a set of values of $x - 4$, add $4$ to each value of $x - 4$ to obtain the corresponding value of $x$, then show the corresponding values of $y = (x - 4)^2$.  The points on the curve $y = (x - 4)^2$ are obtained by matching the $x$-coordinate in the second column with the corresponding $y$-coordinate in the third column.

\begin{array}{c | c | c}
x - 4 & x & y = (x - 4)^2\\ \hline
-3 & 1 & 9\\
-2 & 2 & 4\\
-1 & 3 & 1\\
0 & 4 & 0\\
1 & 5 & 1\\
2 & 6 & 4\\
3 & 7 & 9
\end{array}
The graph of $y = (x - 4)^2$ is shown below in green.  The graph of $y = x^2$ is shown in blue for comparison.

[image: horizontal_translation_of_squaring_function]